# How do you read that a user has stopped inputting?

Tags: python

If you're asking the user to input a sequence of numbers what's the best way in Python to stop waiting for input from the user once they have finished inputting?

For example, in one case a user inputs '1, 44, 100', another case they input '88 22 6 2'.

What's the best way to get the input but not have your program get stuck waiting for more input, or for a specific number to trigger the loop 'break'?

```
 a = int(input())
 while a !="":
    list.append(a)
    a = int(input())
```

I hope you can see my very novice logic behind how to do, but not sure on the best way to actually make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
list = []
While True:
    print "Type quit to exit"
    a = input()
    if a = "quit":
        break
    else:
        list.append(a)
```

This way they can input the numbers one at a time without having to worry about formatting, and when they are done they can write "quit" to move on.

Answer (score 0):

```
# user input format is numbers separated by "," (ie; 1,2,3 or 10, 20, 30)
a = input('enter a list: ')
# 1st use a str operator (split) based on the separator "," 
# this produces a list of strings (ie; ['10','20','30'])
# use list comprehension to conver each element of the str-list to ints
# the list comprehension produces a result with int's (ie; [10,20,30])
list_a = [int(x) for x in a.split(",")]
```

Comment: You should probably explain a little bit.

Comment: added comments :) hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

You should make output a list

```
import sys
numbers = list(map(int, input('Enter numbers: ').split()))
Enter numbers: 2 9
```

Let's check now

```
>>> numbers
[2, 9]
>>> type(numbers)
<class 'list'>
>>>
```